# Convert landmark to Blendshape

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mediapipe

`mediapipe` is so great. But I still can't find a solution to convert from `mediapipe` to `blendshapes`. I need the names of point in `blendshapes` via `mediapipe`.

Is there a way to apply it to `Javascript`? I'm using `Ready Player Me's 3DModel` via react-three-fiber and it's working based on `blendshapes`.

[readyplayermemodel.glb.zip](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/files/10824971/readyplayermemodel.glb.zip)

I found [this issue](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/3421) and https://github.com/google/mediapipe/commit/ba10ae8410ce431f593c95986a230add675e5ccd.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.